# MVC5 keep object in all functions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This question might sound dumb, but I am new to asp.net mvc and can't find the answer to my question.
In my application ( a game) I have a model of the game GameModel (it contains a multidimensional array). What I want is to be able to **use  the same object in every controller I use**. So I create it once and after that use it in every controller function.
Basically there is one view, **and all other functions in the controller edit the object with functions of the model**.

My idea was put the object in a session variable, make a function to check the session variable if the object is not set set the object. But this does not look logic to me, hopefully someone has a better solution.

Comment: So your actual problem is that the session isn't storing your object? You need to put some code down or nobody can help you.

Comment: No, my problem is i dont know the right way to pass an object. my idea was to do it with a session but that feals dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question, you want to keep track of a user's data (game data).

Storing GameModel in Session variable make sense for that scenario.

If you see yourself calling that Session variable from a lot of places, you can create a **BaseController** and keep it there. Then inherit all controllers from it.

For example,

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public GameModel CurrentGameModel
    {
        get
        {
            var model = Session["GameModel"] as GameModel;
            if (model == null)
            {
                model = new GameModel();
                Session["GameModel"] = model;
            }
            return model;
        }
        set { Session["GameModel"] = value; }
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
}
```

***Note:*** You have to keep in mind that if **Application Pool recycles** or **Application crashes**, all data stored in Session variable will be lost.

If you want to persist data, you need to store in persistent storage like database.

Comment: Is this also a smart solution if i want to be able to edit the GameModel  in the session with functinions in my controller ?

Comment: My first choice will be storing data in database. However, storing in Session variable is also acceptable. *(If you access that data in almost every request, it does not make sense to store in **hidden field**. **Singleton** is big no no for that scenario.)*

Comment: How should i run functions on the object ? i tryd  GameModel myGame = (GameModel)Session["GameModel"];
            ViewBag.test = GameModel.stringGetValue(); in my function in the HomeController but it fails.

Comment: If HomeController inherits from BaseController, you can just use - `ViewBag.test = base.CurrentGameModel;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you don't think Session looks good. It's purpose is exactly keeping data per user througout multiple requests.

You could also return the state of the game to the client using hidden fields. That would be even better than Session, given that your game state doesn't change in the server, as a response to someone else's action.

And finally you can use a static property of a class. Static properties in ASP.NET are kept alive througout the application lifecicle and are visible equally to all users. Meaning, if a user writes something there, another user can read it. You can allocate data per user using a `Dictionary<>`, though, where the key is the user Id.